# How to show scores vertically as 2 columns

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a Scores screen that I wanted to show top 5 scores (Level1 and Level2) vertically on the screen with a line that divides them. The scores come from two NSArray objects sorted in descending order. I have been researching on UITableView / UITableViewCell to display multiple columns and it looks it involves more coding for what I'm looking for. Is there any other alternative iOS control that will do the work?

Any ideas?

This is how it may look like

```
Level1      Level2
======      ======

34            46
32            33
24            28
20            21
16            18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

The most elegant solution to do here (despite your reluctance) is to subclass `UITableViewCell` and provide your own implementation of a table cell which has two `UILabel`s for each of the column values, and then you can just draw a vertical line in the middle of your cell (which will turn into a line down the middle of the table view once all the cells are displayed).

Another option is simply to add an additional `UILabel` to the table view cell in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and set the `frame` so that it's on the right hand side of the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    self.textLabel.text = [firstArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];       

    UILabel *secondColumnLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(<customize your values here>];
    secondColumnLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    // any other customization goes here
    secondColumnLabel.text = [secondArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell addSubview:secondColumnLabel];
}
```

Comment: But, how do you arrange the UITextLabels side by side?. Using IB?. I always wonder whether I can have a UITableViewCell on the view and not having UITableView at all as I'm seeing these are two separate controls in the object library in xcode

Comment: Just added a code example above of how to do this programmatically, rather than IB... All you need to do is tweak your `CGRectMake` values to set the frame of the `secondColumnLabel`. Don't have Xcode in front of me right now, but off the top of my head something like `CGRectMake(10,100,100,30)` would probably get you started on an iPhone display... You then need to tweak those values (in case you're unfamiliar, the syntax is `CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)`) -- tweak it until you get the desired result!

Comment: Thanks for the code!. I think I got it. What about the sections and rows for the UITableView?.

Comment: For number of sections, just `return 1;`. For rows, if you **always** have 5 elements in your `NSArray` then it's safe to just `return 5;`. If you want to be safer, then you should `return firstArray.count` (which should be 5, but just in case you change it in the future...). If you want to be super-safe then you should first of all do `NSAssert(firstArray.count == secondArray.count, @"Arrays must be equal in size!");` and *then* `return firstArray.count;`.

Comment: Excellent. Does hardcoding the numbers using CGRectMake good?. Because, I also need to support iPad and possibly future gens of iPad and iPhones. What would be the best strategy here?

Comment: It's up to you, really. In terms of support iPad, you can adjust `CGRect` to do a relative calculation based on `self.view.frame`/`self.view.bounds` which is the `CGRect` of the actual view frame itself (which will obviously be taller and wider on the iPad). You could also use `self.view.center` which will give you a `CGPoint` of the center of the view and work from there. An alternative would be to keep the hardcoded values and check `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad`. In terms of supporting future (wider) devices -- I wouldn't worry about that too much for now.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there are other solutions, but I personally took the road of subclassing `UITableViewCell`. This is a screenshot of how it looks in my app:

[image: screenshot for multi-row UITableViewCell]

Feel free to grab the code for this from [the GitHub repo of my app](https://github.com/herzbube/littlego/). It's a class named `TableViewGridCell` ( under the path `src/ui`). The class has a few limitations that are documented in the header file. In the screenshot you can also see that there is a slight glitch, one cell has its line one pixel off. This still needs fixing...

Answer (score 0):

You can just make two UITableViews and put them next to each other and handle them both independently in your viewcontrller. Or if you wanted you could probably easily make some formatted html and display it in a webview.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I thought about that but do you think two UITableViews would be too much of a overhead for the view to handle with just 5 rows of data in each column?

Comment: Yes, but these would both scroll independently (unless you manually set the scroll of each to mirror the other)

Comment: I don't think it will scroll at all as the scores are always fixed at 5 rows each. The score numbers change though!

Comment: I do not think that it would be too much overhead for handling two UITableViews. Basically you would just declare two UITableViews and make them IBOutlets and in all of your delegate functions just do a check to see which tableview you're dealing with and handle it. Especially if its only 5 elements its an easy fix.